# Kafka producer throws "There are no in-flight requests for node 0" when sending to Azure EventHub with acks=0

Tags: java, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

We’re migrating one of our backend applications to send messages to an Azure EventHub. Before the migration messages were sent to a Kafka Broker, we’re using the EventHub’s Kafka interface.

After the producer in the backend application is triggered, the EventHub successfully receives the sent data. The producer completes the sending successfully. Then the producer throws an exception:

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Uncaught error in kafka producer I/O thread: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are no in-flight requests for node 0
at org.apache.kafka.clients.InFlightRequests.requestQueue(InFlightRequests.java:63) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.InFlightRequests.completeNext(InFlightRequests.java:71) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleCompletedReceives(NetworkClient.java:685) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:469) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163) [kafka-clients-1.1.1.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) [?:?]
```

The producer's configuration:

```
acks=0
max.block.ms=10
linger.ms=1000
batch.size=10000
request.timeout.ms=60000
max.request.size=1000000
metadata.max.idle.ms=180000
metadata.max.age.ms=180000
delivery.timeout.ms=210000
bootstrap.servers=xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net:9093
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"$ConnectionString\" password=\"Endpoint=sb://xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxxxx;SharedAccessKey=*****";
```

After some trial and error, we found out that setting **acks=0** triggers the exception. If set to “1” or “all”, the exception does not occur.

We tried with kafka-clients library 1.1.1 (used in our backend) and 3.0.0 (latest), but it makes no difference. To rule out network effects, we tried it from within the company’s network (behind firewall, proxy) and from a PC outside of the company’s network, it also makes no difference. In all cases the EventHub successfully receives the messages. If acks=0, it’s only the client that shows any exception.

Could this be a bug in the kafka-clients library when used with acks=0 and Azure EventHub? As acks=0 means “fire-and-forget” and the producer should not care whether the messages are received or not. Are we missing any special configuration to make it work?

Comment: We have exactly the same issue, and it doesn't occur when talking to a real Kafka broker.